# Run chkdsk on two disks simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I'm using Windows 7. Is it possible to run chkdsk on two disks simultaneously? I'm running chkdsk on one drive right now, but when I try to start running it on another drive it just closes. I am running this through the GUI (right-click drive->tools->check now).

Comment: How are you trying to run the two instances? I'm guessing in seperate `cmd` windows, but this info might be useful.

Comment: Actually I'm using the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just successfully launched concurrent `chkdsk` runs on different drives from within two seperate elevated `cmd` instances.

But, when using the GUI it will not run a scan on a second drive, but would work individually.

To use the GUI version you normally have to run with "Automatically fix errors" *deselected*. Windows will not run the GUI nor CLI versions in "fix" mode when the drive is live, so you really need to use run at next boot for that.

So, you should be able to achieve what you want via multiple instances of `cmd`, or possibly by setting up a few batch files (one per drive?) and launch them that way.